# Is it possible to create multiple hidden volumes within an encrypted volume?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

You can create an encrypted hidden volume from an outer encrypted volume within Truecrypt or it's fork, Veracrypt... but is it possible to create more than one hidden volume within an outer encrypted volume? For example, an encrypted volume with 2 hidden volumes.

If so, how does one do this?

Comment: This is more of a question for a TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt support site.

Comment: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hidden%20Volume